# pdfmake image error insert

Tags: angularjs, typescript, export-to-pdf, pdfmake

I need to insert an image into PDF , but I get error when the insert , tells me that is not formatted correctly . My code is as follows.

```
public getBase64Image(img : any) {
        // Create an empty canvas element
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        // Copy the image contents to the canvas
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // Get the data-URL formatted image
        // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
        // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
        // will re-encode the image.
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    }
```

the function that converts base64.
which I call the function.

```
exporterPdfHeader:{
                columns: [
                    {  
                        width: 300, alignment: 'left',
                        text: [ 
                                'Pedido de prueba\n\n',
                                'Centro de Trabajo: prueba. Serie: 00.\n\n',
                                'Numped: 38289',
                              ],
                        bold:true,
                        fontSize: 10,
                        margin: [40, 20, 0, 0],
                        height:120,
                    },
                    {
                        width: 140,
                        alignment: 'center',
                        image: 'data:image/png;base64, this.getBase64Image("../imagenes/logoExportarPdf.png")',
                        bold:true, 
                        fontSize: 10,
                        margin: [40, 20, 0, 0],
                        height:80,
                    }
                ]
            },
```

The error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9XZv.png)

On this, I have several questions. Do you need to pass it to base64 ?.
All I wish is to insert a photo into a PDF , which is very simple. As a detail not know if it will be important, I use Angle ui -grid . I program in Typescript .

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're literally passing the string 'data:image/png;base64, this.getBase64Image("../imagenes/logoExportarPdf.png")' as image, not calling the function.

You should use `'data:image/png;base64,'+ this.getBase64Image("../imagenes/logoExportarPdf.png")`